# ClickHouse: access to the source column from select with the same column name

Tags: clickhouse

I cannot access source column value in WHERE block when I have then same column name in SELECT block.

I need to bind MATERIALIZED VIEW on table `test.test` that aggregates records `WHERE idx = 1` and pushes new records to the same table `test.test` with different `idx` value.

```sql
create table test.test (
    idx UInt8,
    val Int64
) engine Memory()
```

```sql
insert into test.test (idx, val)
values 
    (toUInt8(1), toInt64(1)),
    (toUInt8(1), toInt64(2)),
    (toUInt8(1), toInt64(3))
```

```sql
-- Not working
select 2 as idx, sum(val) as val
from test.test
where idx = 1
```

```sql
-- Working fine, but not allowed with materialized view
select _idx as idx, val
from (

    select 2 as _idx, sum(val) as val
    from test.test as t
    where t.idx = 1

)
```

expected

```
┌─idx─┬─val─┐
│   2 │   6 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

actual

```
┌─idx─┬─val─┐
│   2 │   0 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query (just take into account that summing will be applied to a packet of inserted data, not to all rows in table *test.test*. Other words, the view will contain more than one row with *idx==2*) :

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test.test_mv TO test.test AS
SELECT
    toUInt8(2) AS idx,
    val
FROM
(
    SELECT sum(val) AS val
    FROM test.test
    WHERE idx = 1
)
```

I would recommend using the *SummingMergeTree* table engine that more fit for your case:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS test.test_mv2
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree
PARTITION BY idx
ORDER BY idx AS
SELECT
    idx,
    sumState(val) as sum
FROM test.test
GROUP BY idx;



SELECT
    idx,
    sumMerge(sum)
FROM test.test_mv2
GROUP BY idx;
```